# ARCore – Augment an image in realtime with the given coordinates

Tags: java, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm using ARCore in Android Studio. My app will provide the `X`,`Y`,`Z` coordinates. I want the 3D image rendered in definite position.

- How can I achieve this?
- Am I able to render an object when plane is detected and I tapped it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image Detection` and `Plane Detection` are different technologies in ARCore or other AR framework. When you implement ARCore's ***image detection*** feature for placing a 3D model in a scene you can use the [following code](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/augimg-intro/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0).

If you want to implement a ***plane detection*** feature read Google [article](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/tutorials/hello-ar-sample) that contains info not only about plane detection but also about raycasting and hits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have Co-ordinates on an image. I want it to render the 3D image on that Location (Not based on image)

Comment: What's the difference? Can you give me a link with example?

Comment: Basically  I will provide an Image. In that image I will provide a rectangle with co-ordinates (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),
(x4,y4). I want ARCore to render the image between these co-ordinates.
Augmented Images is like if this image, render this.
I am looking the other way with the given co-ordinates.

Comment: As I've understood you right, you have rectangle inside image? So rectangle is an image itself? I think it'll be always not-precise detection because the scale of an ARAnchor entirely depends on scale of image (scale an image and you'll see that a model connected to ARAnchor is scaled too). So all coordinates inside image are highly inexact.

Comment: Yes. I have a Rectangle Box Co-ordinates. I want to have the image in that part only. its ok even not precise detection. How can I have the image rendered based on the co-ordinates